# Windows Server with two vlans

Tags: windows, routing

I have a Windows VM with two NICs on two different vlans.
NIC 1: 10.243.237.167/27 ,gw -10.243.237.1 --vlan 10
NIC 2: 10.243.235.22/24 ,no gw defined.  ---vlan 11

Now when I try to ping/access an IP in vlan 11, i am unable to do so.
When i do a trace, first hop is landing on default gateway instead of exiting via NIC 2.

I then tried to add a static route ,which i believe should not be required ,then too it is making default gateway(10.243.237.1) as the first hop.

static route:

```
netsh interface ipv4 add route 10.243.235.0/24 "PXE" 10.243.235.1
```

Now the interesting thing is when i disconnect and reconnect the NIC  from VMware end it starts pinging Ips on vlan 11 but when i disc/reconnect again it again fails.

So I am not sure what needs to be done to resolve the issue permanently.

Routing table after adding static route:

```
Interface List
 20...00 50 56 84 87 29 ......vmxnet3 Ethernet Adapter #2
 11...00 50 56 84 38 ff ......vmxnet3 Ethernet Adapter
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 12...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
 13...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
 22...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
```

IPv4 Route Table

```
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0   10.243.237.161   10.243.237.167    261
     10.243.235.0    255.255.255.0     10.243.235.1    10.243.235.22      6
    10.243.235.22  255.255.255.255         On-link     10.243.235.22    261
   10.243.237.160  255.255.255.224         On-link    10.243.237.167    261
   10.243.237.167  255.255.255.255         On-link    10.243.237.167    261
   10.243.237.191  255.255.255.255         On-link    10.243.237.167    261
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link    10.243.237.167    261
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     10.243.235.22    261
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    10.243.237.167    261
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     10.243.235.22    261


Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0   10.243.237.161  Default
     10.243.235.0    255.255.255.0     10.243.235.1       1
```

ipconfig /all output:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : ABC
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : XYZ.com
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : XYZ.COM

Ethernet adapter PXE:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : vmxnet3 Ethernet Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-50-56-84-87-29
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::443d:5c6a:4c1e:a713%20(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.243.235.22(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 335564886
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1E-E1-D2-6E-00-50-56-84-38-FF
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : vmxnet3 Ethernet Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-50-56-84-38-FF
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::d84e:9a5:16cc:b2d3%11(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.243.237.167(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.224
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.243.237.161
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 184569942
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1E-E1-D2-6E-00-50-56-84-38-FF
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.169.66.196
                                       10.169.194.196
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{AF767DF7-D092-437C-B120-5D0A59C1D8E0}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{7F24A98F-1CF1-4B00-B313-C2064AC12285}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{6C943185-2420-454E-AFFC-3206CB9640E6}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

Comment: Please add the output of `ipconfig /all`.

Comment: I have added the ipconfig /all output to the main question.

I understand I should not be adding static route but i don't understand why   you say it should not be accepted by the OS ?

Comment: The configuration is correct; the server shoud already know how to reach the second network. Possibly a bug in the VMware drivers?

Comment: The command is fundamentally wrong because it says "you can reach this network through a gateway which is on this network, too", creating a logic loop: the gateway must be used to reach the network, but the network must be used to reach the gateway. This simply doesn't make sense.

Comment: Some one asked a similar question for windows 10 .
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking/ip-routing-table-issue/48c22cd5-09c0-40e1-9187-1b44d3c2b735

If windows OS is not following its own routing table then how do we say is a VMware driver bug ?

Comment: This is not a routing table issue; no explicit routes are needed to reach a directly attached network (that's what "on-link" means in the routing table); routes for directly attached networks are automatically created when you configure a network interface.

Comment: Thanks Massimo.But in what way could be due to a VMware driver ?  How do I go about resolving it?

Comment: I dont' really know, this is a very strange issue; as I said, the routes to access directly-connected networks should be automatically added by the OS upon configuring the network interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

A static route is not needed; if the server has a network interface on the 10.243.235.0/24 network, it should already know how to reach that network.

Also, your static route is wrong: it tells the server to reach the 10.243.235.0/24 network *through the gateway at 10.243.235.1*, which can't possibly work, because the IP address of the gateway is in that very same network (I'm actually quite surprised the command was even accepted).

What is missing here is a route telling the server it can reach the 10.243.235.0/24 network through its interface with IP address 10.243.235.22:

```
10.243.235.22  255.255.255.0           On-link     10.243.235.22    261
```

But it should not be manually configured, because the very fact of having a network interface with that IP address and subnet mask should automatically set it up.

Please add the output of `ipconfig /all`, so we can check if something is wrong in your network configuration.